# Does repetition of same rules for each major crawler bot makes sense in robots.txt?

Tags: seo, robots.txt

SEO is a bit of arcane topic and sometimes I encounter strange practics which seemingly aren't backed up by any advice but still persists.
Now I mean something like this:

```
User-agent: Googlebot
Disallow: /page/
Disallow: /ajax
Disallow: *?back*
User-agent: Yandex
Disallow: /page/
Disallow: /ajax
Disallow: *?back*
...
User-agent: *
Disallow: /page/
Disallow: /ajax
Disallow: *?back*
```

Does this makes some sense? Those rules are really totally same.

Comment: Is there ever a use case where you'd want a specific bot to visit, but not others? I can think of one case if a bot needs to visit for services you signed up with (AdSense, AdWords)...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is redundant and unnecessary.

```
/* Applies to all robots */
User-agent: *
Disallow: /page/
Disallow: /ajax
Disallow: *?back*
```

Comment: If `/page/`, `/ajax`, and `*?back*` should also be disallowed for `Googlebot`, you would have to repeat these rules for the `User-agent: Googlebot` record.

Comment: The wild card *, which means all user-agents, also applies to Googlebot, no need for another separate entry.